# Make an SVG line appear as an animation "following" the line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using the following code to plot a line on a bar chart:

```
data.forEach(function(elem, index) {
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(elem)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("color", colors[index])
        .attr("d", line);
});
```

Where `data` is a multidimensional array, each of whose elements is another array of the form `[{x: 0, y: whatever}, {x: 0.5, y: another-y-value}, ...]`, i.e. a set of points for the line to go through. What I want to do is to make the line appear as if it is being drawn, i.e. instead of making it appear instantly, I want it to visibly extend from the first point through the second, and so on, while retaining its curvature. This is what it currently looks like (for an arbitrary function mapping x to y):

[image]

Comment: manipulate stroke-dasharray to do that, there's plenty of question and answers covering that.

Comment: How about clip into a rectangle, with width transition from 0 to max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sorry for double answer, this one is credited to @RobertLongson]

There is a very nice example using `stroke-dasharray` [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592). Add the following then add `.call(transition)` to your path.

```
function transition(path) {
  path.transition()
    .duration(7500)
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
    .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).call(transition); });
}

function tweenDash() {
  var l = this.getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  return function(t) { return i(t); };
}
```

Comment: As a side note for anyone browsing this, this answer works but makes the path disappear and repeats the animation every time it is finished. To get rid of this effect, remove `.each("end", function() { d3.select(this).call(transition); })` from the `transition()` function definition.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to `clip` the line to a rectangle, whose width transitions smoothly from 0 to the maximum width. See http://jsfiddle.net/pLL30tcz/2/

Add the following to your `<svg>`:

```
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="0" height="400" />
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
```

Then clip your line with  `.style("clip-path","url(#clipPath)")` on your path element. Finally the drawing effect can be achieved as follows:

```
d3.select("#clipPath rect")
  .attr("width", "0")
  .transition()
  .duration(4000)
  .attr("width","400")
```

You just need to adjust the coordinates to your needs. The only drawback is that the speed is not uniform along the line, but only along the x-axis, so the difference can be visible between almost-horizontal and almost-vertical parts of the path.

Comment: This is good, and I'll use it if there isn't an alternative, but it doesn't quite make the animation as if the line was being drawn. If the line were to cross over itself, or go backwards, it wouldn't work.